# Se puede cambiar el estilo de un Alert window

Tags: javascript, html, css3

se puede cambiar el estilo de un alert() es decir alguna funcion para poder hacerlo o siempre tiene que ser del mismo modo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No puedes. El alert window es nativo del navegador y no se puede cambiar el estilo.
Tu podrías crear uno propio o quizás descargar algún plugin el cual te pueda hacer la vida más fácil.

Podrías utilizar [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/), es muy fácil de aprender y tiene bonito diseño (aunque tu también puedes darle tu propio estilo).

Aquí esta otro llamado [jQuery-confirm](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/)

Encuentra el que se adapte más a tus necesidades y gustos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la informacion

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el compañero Hoose, puedes usar [SweetAlert](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert). Muy facil de implementar y personalizar.

Añades los archivos necesarios y funcionar.

```
<script src="dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/sweetalert.css">
```

Y a funcionar.

```
swal("Hello world!");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias estoy agradecido